# JAX-RS Client: Many instances inside KeepAliveCache

Tags: java, rest, jersey, jax-rs, cxf

I'm running a Java microservice issuing many REST client requests using the Apache CXF implementation of the JAX RS `Client` class. While repeating 10 concurrent requests I see 350+ map entries inside `sun.net.www.http.KeepAliveCache` consuming a significant amount of heap memory. This is memory I'd like to free.

In this example I'm issuing the same request to the same host (target) all the time, and I don't understand why that many entries are kept in the cache. Wouldn't roughly 10 be enough? I'm also unable to figure out how connections / client instances / ... can be re-used.

In my code I only create a single instance of the `Client` class. This is then used with `client.target(...).request().get()`.

I'd be happy to get some hints of how to use a connection manager with CXF - assuming this would help with my problem.

As a side note, a lot of CPU time is spent in `SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake`. If this can be avoided (it is the same host all the time!), I'd be happy to get some hints on that as well.

EDIT: I close the `response` objects using a try-finally very soon after reading the entity out of it. I never close the `Client` instance, though.

EDIT 2: Re-using the same `Client` instance is not a good idea, as Apache CXF does not provide a thread-safe implementation. As I don't see a performance hit, I'll just create a new `Client` whenever I need an instance. This is not related to the problem outlined here, though.

EDIT 3: Same issue with Jersey client.